# How to control Spring Boot Admin Server spring cloud kubernetes based service discovery to use HTTP instead of HTTPS

Tags: openshift, spring-boot-actuator, service-discovery, fabric8, spring-boot-admin

I have `spring boot admin server deployed in openshift` with the help of fabric8 maven plugin

And also `i have several applications deployed in openshift`.

`Spring boot admin server (SBAS) use spring cloud kubernetes discovery` to discover services (applications) registered / running in namespace / cluster, which is automatic client discovery.

SBAS discovered as expected, its fine but some applications shown / registered in `SBAS use http and some use https` to check the health as like below

[image: SBDS]

I have no idea, why SBAS use http for some apps and for https for some apps to check the health.

Since `SBAS use https and port 8443 it shows applications are offline` but those applications `are exposed in http 8080 only`

I have compared applications code and openshift configurations but i don't see any difference and how to fix this issue.

I am new to all above concepts could some one help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find solution for this issue, but i did work around which helped me.
Since i am using only one port 8080, i have deleted other ports such as 8443 and 8778 via openshif yml as shown below. but you have you have to expose more ports this won't help.

[image: Work Around]